# Android: MediaRecorder @ Native code

Tags: android, encoding, streaming, multimedia

Playing with the MediaRecorder Java code I have found the MediaRecorder class to be quite limited, there is no way to control the media before it is encoded/compressed, and, there is no way to control the result, file, socket, transport:MPEG2-TS, MP4 'moof' position, ...

With windows enviroment DirectShow/MediaFoundation provide fine access and control of the media pipeline.

I wonder, is there any LowLevel NDK API for the MediaRecorder that enable some of the above mentioned functionality?

I would really like to avoid implementing a native C++ MediaRecorder my-self...

Any Help will B appreciated.

~Nadav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Android's openSL es. Look at this example app:

http://codesearch.google.com/#CRBM04-7BoA/ndk/platforms/android-9/samples/native-audio/